Deleting item with relationship from List causes crash
In your app we are using a NavigationSplitView and SwiftData(with CloudKit) to display the data. When trying to delete items  from the SwiftUi-List (using SwitUI EditButton)we are often confronted with unreproducible crashes that seem to be caused by the relationship between your models being used.
In the DetailView of the NavigationSplitView we show a list of Views (data held by SheetContent), only the last view in this list is editable. To keep track of the content in DetailView another model is used (SheetItem) which has a relationship with SheetContent and which is fetched via @Query in the View that builds the NavigationSplitView.
What happens in the case of a crash is that the data of the query seems not to be correctly updated after an item was deleted.
We can see that  when the list is rebuild also the just deleted SheetItem is still included but obviously the information about the related SheetContent is gone as the crash happens attempting to load the current editable one via a computed property.
Here we return the last SheetContent in the list or create one if the list is empty which is the case when a new SheetItem is created.
However the line of code where the crash happens differs when using an actual device or the simulator as you can see in the screenshot below.
On the simulator it fails attempting to read it from the now empty array in class SheetItem.
On the iPhone it tries to create a new SheetContent because of the empty list, failing then passing self which seems to be invalid by that time to the constructor of SheetContent.
So we are assuming some sort of timing problem here. Is there anything wrong with or code (see shortened version below) or any hints how to track this further down?
Help is very much appreciated
Screenshot simulator

Screenshot iPhone

struct SheetsNavigationView: View {
    @Query(sort: \SheetItem.order) private var items: [SheetItem]
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    
    @State var sheetsNavigationViewModel = SheetsNavigationViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView(columnVisibility: $sheetsNavigationViewModel.visibility) {
            List(selection: $sheetsNavigationViewModel.selection) {
                if items.isEmpty {
                    Button(action: addItem, label: {
                        Text("New sheet")
                    })
                }
                else {
                    ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                        NavigationLink {
                            sheetView(for: item)
                        } label: {
                            Text("Sheet \(item.sheetName)")
                        }
                    }
                    .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
                }
            }
        } detail: {
            navigationDestinationView()
        }
    }
    
    private func deleteItems(offsets: IndexSet) {
        for index in offsets {

            if items[index].sheetNumber == displayedSheetNumber  {
                sheetsNavigationViewModel.selection = nil
            }
            
            modelContext.delete(items[index])

            try? modelContext.save()
        }
    }
}

@Model
final class SheetItem: Identifiable {
    var order: Int?
    var sheetNumber: Int?
    var sheetName: String?
    
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade, inverse: SheetContent.respectiveSheetItem)
    var content: [SheetContent]?
    var currentContentId: String?
    
    var currentContent: SheetContent {
        get {
            if let currentContentId,
               let foundContent = content?.first(where: { oneItem in
                   oneItem.contentId?.uuidString == currentContentId
               }) {
                return foundContent
            }
            else {
                let newContent = SheetContent(respectiveSheetItem: self)
                currentContentId = newContent.contentId?.uuidString
                return newContent
            }
        }
    }
}

@Model
final class SheetContent {
    var contentId: UUID?

    var respectiveSheetItem: SheetItem?
    
    init(contentId: UUID? = UUID(), respectiveSheetItem: SheetItem? = nil) {
        self.contentId = contentId
        self.respectiveSheetItem = respectiveSheetItem
    }
}


The code doesn't compile because several parts are missing so maybe try to add a MRE. Or remove the computed property currentContent from SheetItem and see if that fixes the problem. You should not have a property that might create another object when you access it.

Thank you @JoakimDanielson and sorry for my late response. I will try to find some time creating running demo. As for the computed property: I honestly don't really understand how this can be related to the crash. The problem the way I understand is not this property but the fact that the number of items in the query did not change after deletion. In next ForEach call in SheetsNavigationView the deleted item is still included but without having a BackingData (2nd screenshot) when building a new SheetContent. In the crash on the simulator the computed property is not involved (1st screenshot).
